# Does rails store data relationships in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using relationships in rails are they stored in the database so all foreign keys are stored in the tables and such like or are all relationships controlled via the software?
Thanks in Advance
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign keys are stored in the tables.  The `has_many` and `belongs_to` declarations in the models are only there to create the attributes used to access the relationships.